# NodeJS get async return value (callback)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have read around the internet about callbacks but I just can't understand them in my case.

I have this function, and it logs to console when it runs.
However I now need this response in another function and I am struggling to do so.

```
var asyncJobInfo = function(jobID, next) {

    var oozie = oozieNode.createClient({ config: config });

    var command = 'job/' + jobID + '?show=info';

    console.log("running oozie command: " + command);

    oozie.get(command, function(error, response) {

    console.log("*****response would dump to console here:*****");
//  console.log(response);
    return response;
    });
};
```

This is where I should get it:
(This obviously doesn't work because it doesn't wait for the response.)

```
exports.getJobInfoByID = function(req, res) {

    var jobIDParam = req.params.id;
    res.send(asyncJobInfo(jobIDParam));
}
```

I really struggle to wrap my head around callbacks and I'm staring myself blind here.

Comment: no you can't get return value, better pass `req & res` to `asyncJobInfo` function & do `res.send` at the place of `return response`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Callbacks can't return a value as the code they would be returning to has already executed.

So you can do a couple things. One pass a callback function and once your async function gets the data call the callback and pass the data. Or pass the response object and use it in your async function

Passing a callback

```
exports.getJobInfoByID = function(req, res) {
    var jobIDParam = req.params.id;
    asyncJobInfo(jobIDParam,null,function(data){
       res.send(data);
    });
}

var asyncJobInfo = function(jobID, next,callback) {
    //...
    oozie.get(command, function(error, response) {
       //do error check if ok do callback
       callback(response);
    });
};
```

Passing response object

```
exports.getJobInfoByID = function(req, res) {
    var jobIDParam = req.params.id;
    asyncJobInfo(jobIDParam,null,res);
}

var asyncJobInfo = function(jobID, next,res) {
    //...
    oozie.get(command, function(error, response) {
       //do error check if ok do send response
       res.send(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really needed to see an example with my own code that I understand.
I was aware that callbacks can't have return values I just didn't understand the way it was supposed to work.

Answer (score 4):

In async world you can't return values. Whatever needs to be done when the value is ready should be executed inside the callback. Another alternative is using promises. You'll need the `es6-promise` package:

```
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;

var asyncJobInfo = function(jobID) {
  var oozie = oozieNode.createClient({config: config});
  var command = 'job/' + jobID + '?show=info';
  console.log("running oozie command: " + command);
  // Creates a new promise that wraps
  // your async code, and exposes two callbacks:
  // success, and fail.
  return new Promise(function(success, fail) {
    oozie.get(command, function(error, response) {
      if (error) {
        fail(error);
      } else {
        success(response);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Now you can use the promise and pass the callbacks that will run once it is resolved:

```
exports.getJobInfoByID = function(req, res) {
  asyncJobInfo(req.params.id).then(function(data) {
    res.send(data)
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
};
```

The above can be shortened:

```
exports.getJobInfoByID = function(req, res) {
  asyncJobInfo(req.params.id)
    .then(res.send.bind(res))
    .catch(console.error);
};
```